# How to stop spam from ConfDriver of TU Wien?

Tags: spam

This year I submitted a paper to a conference that used ConfDriver of TU Wien. From the time of submission, I started receiving **a lot** of CFPs from conferences that also use ConfDriver.

All the conferences seem solid, and the emails are from researchers of well-known institutions. However, I find it really annoying, because they are completely unrelated to my research area, and sometime unrelated to Computer Science.

There is no option to "unsubscribe" to these kinds of CFPs, and there is nothing in common to make a filter in email client.

By the way, I find ConfDriver much worse than EasyChair, and it even doesn't notify the co-authors when making (or updating) a submission.

---

### UPDATE

I understand that some people from TU Wien may be upset with this question. But what this ConfDriver is doing is really spam, and it is really annoying. Unlike spams from junk conferences, this kind of spam is much more difficult to block, since the emails are from well-known institutions, e.g. MIT etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use spam filtering in an unnamed email client

Comment: @EnergyNumbers: I do know how to use spam filtering, but in this case it is impossible to use it.

Comment: _There is no option to "unsubscribe" to these kinds of CFPs_ is unclear to me. Most of the CFPs I received has the option to "unsubscribe" either at the beginning or at the end of the e-mail. Did you check? Or there are too many those e-mails you didn't bother to look at?

Comment: @scaaahu: I check both in the CFPs and in my ConfDriver account. I can't delete this account, because there are solid conferences in my field which are using this system.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "Dexa Conference" was set up at the TU Wien using ConfDriver. The [website](https://confdriver.ifs.tuwien.ac.at/dexa2010/) notes that "In case of difficulties please contact confdriver@ifs.tuwien.ac.at". Maybe you should give that a try.

BTW, ironically one of the [workshops](http://confdriver.ifs.tuwien.ac.at/dexa2013/home/167) was about "Defence against Spam in Electronic Communication".